# Google Ads Malware

Tags: jquery, google-ads-api

Google ads did a scan of my WordPress site running in the Stockholm template and found the following malware - http://www.7lpp.org/jquery.js

Where do I find and disable/remove this?

Answer (score 0):

depends.... is this a file which is needed in wordpress your templates or your plugins? if not, rename the file, check if everything is still working (everything !!!!) and then use the delete button. If the file is needed, try to find the resource needing this file(probably the functionality which is not working anymore) and download the resource again to your pc. then exchange the file with the one on your webserver. Then rescan your webpage again. If you still find problem in the same file. Try exchanging the plugin for something else, or check with the developers of that plugin.

**Alternatively:**
download [this](https://www.inforapid.de/html/srdownload.htm) tool (best tool ever created)
download your webspace
Open inforapid and enter everything like in the pic below
copy paste following line into "In Files" to describe the files in which the programm should search
*.htm | *.html | *.conf | *.ini | *.bat | *.txt | *.css | *.js | *.php | *.access | *.conv | *.cnf | *.csv | *.xml | *.py

[image]

After that press on start and find all files and lines where there is an entry to this domain. You might want to check the code first, but you could also replace every mentioning of this malitous code/domain in all your files

[image]

Comment: I have  no idea where to find it or actually even how to look for it. I've updated all the plugins I could and removed the ones I don't use anymore. I have other sites that run on the same template - but they don't get that error.

Comment: do you have access to your webspace? if so, connect with an FTP client e.g. filezilla and click on the root folder and then press on the search button. there enter the name of the file. alternatively you could download the whole webpage to your device and then search for the file with windows search or tools like inforapid. Can you copy the whole error description/display into your post

Comment: I'm going to try that. Thank you. Our AdWords guy just said Google picked it up when they scanned the site. I'll ask them what the exact error was if this doesn't help.

Comment: Found no entries - might have been in one of the plugins I deleted.